# Can you run a websocket client in EU4 server mode?

Tags: client-server, server, web, websocket

Is it possible to build a websocket client (eg [using blueprints](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/blueprintwebsocket?sessionInvalidated=true)) and then package this into an EU4 server (like suggested [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Gameplay/Networking/HowTo/DedicatedServers/index.html)).

If so, would this mean that the EU4 server's websocket client could then connect to a different server app being run using say javascript or golang?

Comment: What do you observe when you try this? Do you encounter a blocker or error anywhere along the way?

Comment: I'm trying to see if this idea makes sense or whether it's possible before trying it

Comment: If it makes enough sense to you to ask, it's probably worth trying! And that's both faster than waiting for one of us to do the experiment on your behalf, and more informative, because you'll be able to measure the complexity/performance in detail.

Comment: I think you have the wrong idea, the point is to see if anyone has done this before. Since I've not used unreal before it will take me a long time to try this